# Does oracle workspace manager work with oracle xe 11g

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, oracle-xe

According to this forum it can be using a patch but I need a support identifier to access patches.
https://community.oracle.com/thread/340084?start=0&tstart=0

This describes how to install workspace manager on custom databases using the 
owminst.plb file which doesn't seem to come with xe
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14253/long_inst.htm#g640808

I've searched through many web pages and I can't find a process for installing workspace manager on an oracle xe installation.  Is the only way to get a patch or just download SE?

Comment: You won't get any patches or support from Oracle for XE. Hardly surprising, since it's free. It appears that you need one of the paid server editions.